# How do I get PDO / SQLite to report an error?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I'm sorry for such a newb question, but I've been reading tutorials all night and I cannot get a basic PDO / SQLite chain going (create, insert, select). I made this code as simple as I can, while following the rules from the tutorials, however it returns an empty Array for a result, but also doesn't give me error saying why the create-table or insert didn't work. Thank you so much for reading!

```php
// connect
try {
  $db = new PDO('sqlite::memory:');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
// create
try {
  $db->exec("create table cats (
      name varchar(255),
      meows int
    );");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo 'error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
// insert
$statement = $db->prepare("insert into cats (name, meows) values (':name', :meows)");
$statement->bindValue(':name', "Fluffy");
$statement->bindValue(':meows', 15);
try {
  $statement->execute();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo 'error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
// select
$statement = $db->prepare("select * from cats");
try {
  $statement->execute();
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "error: " . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
// print
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Apologies! I finally found out that this line will turn on errors:

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

The error, I'm getting is `General error: 25 bind or column index out of range` on the insert statement. Since, that problem is different than the title, this post will have to be considered answered, and I will now move on to figuring out what this error is. Again, I am sorry for not finding this answer before I posted the question.

Comment: For anyone else like me who spent forever trying to figure out the `General error: 25 bind or column index out of range` error - the problem was the single quotes around `':name'` - apparently PDO somehow knows what the column type is and either adds the quotes automatically or communicates with the database in a way that does not require writing standard SQL statements - holy crap, that was stressful!